# iOS GCM notification sending, but not showing

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to implement GCM in my iOS app. Everything seems to work fine, the app is connecting to GCM and getting a registration ID back. If I send a notification to that regid using Postman it works and I get a success response back from Google. However, whatever I try, the notification isn't actually shown on the device.

The post messsage to the GCM servers I'm using is

```
{
    "to" : "RegID",
    "content_available" : true,
    "notification" : {
        "body" : "Test Body",
        "title" : "Test Title"
    }
}
```

which gives me the response:

```
{
    "multicast_id": 6594175386712804014,
    "success": 1,
    "failure": 0,
    "canonical_ids": 0,
    "results": [
        {
            "message_id": "0:1443445858075083%c4cfa24dc4cfa24d"
        }
    ]
}
```

This makes me believe there is something wrong with the code in my app. Below I've pasted all the relevant code. I've written the code 3 times without success, first following the tutorial and editing it to fit in my app properly, second time I copied the code from the tutorial and the third time I got the example app from the Github repo and copied everything relevant to GCM over.

AppDelegate:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate  {

    var window: UIWindow?

    var connectedToGCM = false
    var gcmSenderID: String?
    var registrationToken: String?
    var registrationOptions = [String: AnyObject]()
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    let registrationKey = "onRegistrationCompleted"
    let messageKey = "onMessageReceived"
    let notification = "isNotificationEnabled"

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Google Cloud Messaging
        var configureError:NSError?
        GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError(&configureError)
        assert(configureError == nil, "Error configuring Google services: \(configureError)")
        gcmSenderID = GGLContext.sharedInstance().configuration.gcmSenderID

        var types: UIUserNotificationType = UIUserNotificationType.Badge |
            UIUserNotificationType.Alert |
            UIUserNotificationType.Sound
        var settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
        UIUserNotificationSettings( forTypes: types, categories: nil )
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings( settings )
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

        var gcmConfig = GCMConfig.defaultConfig()
        GCMService.sharedInstance().startWithConfig(gcmConfig)

        return true
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {              
        GCMService.sharedInstance().connectWithHandler({
            (NSError error) -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                println("Could not connect to GCM: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            } else {
                self.connectedToGCM = true
                println("Connected to GCM")
                // ...
            }
        })

    }

    func application( application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken
        deviceToken: NSData ) {
            println(deviceToken)
            // [END receice_apns_token]
            // [START get_gcm_reg_token]
            // Create a config and set a delegate that implements the GGLInstaceIDDelegate protocol.
            var instanceIDConfig = GGLInstanceIDConfig.defaultConfig()
            // Start the GGLInstanceID shared instance with that config and request a registration
            // token to enable reception of notifications
            GGLInstanceID.sharedInstance().startWithConfig(instanceIDConfig)
            registrationOptions = [kGGLInstanceIDRegisterAPNSOption:deviceToken,
                kGGLInstanceIDAPNSServerTypeSandboxOption:true]
            GGLInstanceID.sharedInstance().tokenWithAuthorizedEntity(gcmSenderID,
                scope: kGGLInstanceIDScopeGCM, options: registrationOptions, handler: registrationHandler)
            // [END get_gcm_reg_token]
    }

    func registrationHandler(registrationToken: String!, error: NSError!) {
        if (registrationToken != nil) {
            self.registrationToken = registrationToken
            println("Registration Token: \(registrationToken)")
            let userInfo = ["registrationToken": registrationToken]
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(
                self.registrationKey, object: nil, userInfo: userInfo)
        } else {
            println("Registration to GCM failed with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            let userInfo = ["error": error.localizedDescription]
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(
                self.registrationKey, object: nil, userInfo: userInfo)
        }
    }

    func onTokenRefresh() {
        // A rotation of the registration tokens is happening, so the app needs to request a new token.
        println("The GCM registration token needs to be changed.")
        GGLInstanceID.sharedInstance().tokenWithAuthorizedEntity(gcmSenderID,
            scope: kGGLInstanceIDScopeGCM, options: registrationOptions, handler: registrationHandler)
    }


    func application( application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
        println("Notification received: \(userInfo)")
        // This works only if the app started the GCM service
        GCMService.sharedInstance().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo);
        // Handle the received message
        // Invoke the completion handler passing the appropriate UIBackgroundFetchResult value
        // [START_EXCLUDE]
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(messageKey, object: nil,
            userInfo: userInfo)
    }
```

If anyone asked a similar question before let me know, I wasn't able to find one that described my situation properly.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your HTTP request looks fine. But there are couple differences between your implementation and the [Google sample project](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/ios/gcm/GcmExampleSwift/ViewController.swift). You should try to copy and paste all the lines from that sample project, or download the sample project.

Comment: What exactly in your link takes care of showing a notification? Looks like mostly UI code. From what I understood from the Google tutorial the code in their Appdelegate should be enough to show a simple notification?

Comment: I never thought that apple would let you use any push notifications that are not APNS on IOS.

Comment: @Dan the [AppDelegate.swift](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/ios/gcm/GcmExampleSwift/AppDelegate.swift) in the sample project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't implemented the appropriate notification callback. You need to implement

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
    didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject],
    fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

   // Do something with userInfo
   // call fetchCompletionHandler with the appropriate UIBackgroundFetchResult 
}
```

Silent Push Notifications(i.e. ones with `content-available` flag set) call the above `UIApplicationDelegate` method instead of `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:`.

Also make sure you've added `remote-notification` value to the `UIBackgroundModes` in your `Info.plist`.

Comment: You are a god, this fixed my issue. Is there any way to update a UITableView using the fetchCompletionHandler?

Comment: You can do whatever update you want before calling `fetchCompletionHandler`. The handler is just used to notify iOS that you are done with whatever update you wanted to do.